# Get array from one line in Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to get array from one line in sheet. First I wrote this

```js
let shSettings = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("НАСТРОЙКИ");
let kuDeads = shSettings.getRange("A1:N1").getValues();
```

Next I need to get length of my array and check the value in item with my variable

```js
for (var j = 1; j < kuDeads.length; j ++){
  colJ = j + 1;
  if (shSettings.getRange(1,colJ).getValue() == priorKU){
    deadDays = shSettings.getRange(row,colJ).getValue();
    break;
  }
}
```

But I get the info, that the length = 1. And cycle is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer of arul selvan.

To use `getValue()` (and `setValue()`) in a loop is not the best idea if there are more than a couple iterations. It can be painfully slow if you have dozens of hundreds cells. You need to use `getVaues()` and process the 2d array in your script.

In your case it can be done about this way:

```
let data = shSettings.getRange("A2:N").getValues(); 

for (var j = 1; j < kuDeads[0].length; j++) {
  if (data[0][j] == priorKU) {
    deadDays = data[row-1][j-1];
    break;
  }
}
```

It will work much faster.

Answer (score 1):

`length` gives the length of the array (number of rows).

`kuDeads[0].length` gives the number of columns.

```js
let shSettings = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("НАСТРОЙКИ");
let kuDeads = shSettings.getRange("A1:N1").getValues();
```

```js
for (var j = 1; j < kuDeads[0].length; j ++){
  colJ = j + 1;
  if (shSettings.getRange(1,colJ).getValue() == priorKU){
    deadDays = shSettings.getRange(row,colJ).getValue();
    break;
  }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Range Class getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).